# C++ Eclipse debugger: "Cannot find bounds of current function" and doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I am using Ubuntu for one of the first times and eclipse's debugger has given me more trouble than I can deal with. For the moment I just want to try to figure out how to get the "Cannot find bounds of current function" to stop so I can see where my flow of control goes awry.

I know this is a vague question, but I'm willing to quickly supply any sort of information necessary. I've been googling info for about 2 hours and switching on and off different things to no avail.

I'm using Version: 3.4.1 (I believe the newest one)

Also, my breakpoints won't always works (probably about a 25% success rate) even when I set them before the build. My cout<<  or printf also can't print before the programs blows up. This makes me think it's some sort of concurrent process that is outpacing the debugger, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I would greatly appreciate any help. I'll be around.

Answer (score 4):

Not an [unheard-of problem](http://www.nabble.com/debug-problem-in-Eclipse3.2.2-%2B-CDT3.1.2-td18569813.html)

I suppose you can confirm that:

- all the shared libraries are compiled with -g flag (debug) ?
- and the output application binary file seems to be ok because it runs correctly in command line ?
- you are not compiling with some framwework (like [Qt4](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products)) which would [require qmake to be run](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg14361.html) to generate the project file to which you add "`CONFIG += qt debug`" ?
- you have no warning of any kind during the build ? (like this ["Clock skew detected"](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg12605.html) message)

---

The point of all this is:

**Somewhere, one of the libs or your own program do not have "debug" information in it.**

The -g flag can be set directly in the makefile (and is not particularly dependent of the OS in this instance).

Example (***not targeted for Linux***)

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -Wno-deprecated -g
DEFINES = -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DLITTLE_ENDIAN

##########################

COMPILE=$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEFINES)
LINK=$(CXX)

UNRAR_OBJ=filestr.o recvol.o rs.o scantree.o

OBJECTS=rar.o strlist.o strfn.o pathfn.o

.cpp.o:
    $(COMPILE) -D$(WHAT) -c -g $<

all:    unrar

clean:
    @rm -f *.o *.bak *~

unrar:    WHAT=UNRAR
unrar:    $(OBJECTS) $(UNRAR_OBJ)
    @rm -f makeunrar
    $(LINK) -Wl,-s -g -o unrar $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
$(UNRAR_OBJ) $(LIBS)   

sfx:    WHAT=SFX_MODULE
sfx:    $(OBJECTS)
    @rm -f default.sfx
    $(LINK) -Wl,-s -g -o default.sfx $(LDFLAGS)
$(OBJECTS) -DSFX_MODULE

g++ -O2 -Wno-deprecated -g  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DLITTLE_ENDIAN -DUNRAR -c -g
rar.cpp
[...]
g++ -Wl,-s -g -o unrar  rar.o strlist.o ...
```

Here, that makefile contains a huge trap:

```
g++ -Wl,-s -o unrar  rar.o strlist.o ...
```

`-s` stands for "strip" meaning all the debug informations generated before are lost in the final output. So do check also your link options.

Comment: I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to linux so bear with me (never had anyone explain something to me in person).
-g flag - I've definitely heard of it, but I looked everywhere in my directories/properties and could find it.

Comment: Maybe gdb is a subsitute? No warnings on build. I don't think I'm compiling with some special framework. I believe I'm using gcc (I downloaded it from the package explorer. I tried following some instruction like these:

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/3243248/eclipse-debug

They looked more familiar but as for a server I don't really have one and I don't think I need to set it up (right?).  I did everything else the document said and nothing changed (except having to fix the server errors)